# Mobile View mode in pdf viewer flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile, view, pdf-viewer

I tried different PDF viewer programs, but none seem to have a mobile view mode like WPS Office. In WPS Office, there's a feature that converts to full-screen mode for better viewing, no need to zoom in, and texts are visible. Despite trying different packages, I haven't found any that offer a similar feature. Do you have any suggestions?

I tried to use pdftotext to extract text from a PDF and display it using HTML widget. But, this method removes images, and there are issues with text alignment

Answer (score 2):

May be this package will help you. [syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_pdfviewer). It allows you to view PDFs in full screen on mobile devices within your app.

Comment: I am using this package, but still i haven't found that option. If you ever used WPS office, it has a feature called mobile view, which converts to full screeen, with changes of font size, .. of texts.. Font size of the texts will be bigger, no need to scroll left or right.